# Rank each number by position in a list of arrays - Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list of arrays and I want to rank the numbers against the similar positioned numbers in the other arrays  in the list.

```
x = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]
```

I tried the following and it ranked each numbers against all the numbers and also 
the smallest number is ranked 1

```
scipy.stats.rankdata(x)

array([ 9.,5.5,1.,2., 3.,4.,5.5,7.,8. ])
```

I want to rank with largest number ranked 1 and each number only ranked against the number that is in the same position in each array of the list.

This is the output that I need.

```
[[1,2,3]
[3,3,2],
[2,1,1]]
```

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Please read the question better before making a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use magic `numpy.argsort`.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[12,7,3],
              [4 ,5,6],
              [7 ,8,9]])

y = x.shape[0] - np.argsort(np.argsort(x, axis = 0), axis = 0)
```

Output:

```
In [111]: y
Out[111]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the axis along which to rank. By default it gives the rank according to the ascending order. You can use your knowledge of the shape of your data to turn it into what you want. Example with your data

```
x = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]
3-scipy.stats.mstats.rankdata(x,axis=0)+1
# you will get
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
      [ 3.,  3.,  2.],
      [ 2.,  1.,  1.]])
```